# In an asp.net core project, Can I assume an option for user to add a field to SQL table and previous forms changing dynamically?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, web-applications, dynamic-forms, dynamicform

I have a web application that created with asp.net core. My model is a SQL database.
For any table, there is a controller and some views to insert, update, delete, and display data.
(views are use CSS, bootstrap, java script, J Query.)
Can I design an environment for user that can add fields to a table and all of views that are relevant to this table will changed automatically?

In other words, user can change tables without help of a programmer who design insert or edit or display forms, and SQL database.

Can I give this option to user in asp.net core

Comment: Can it be created: Yes. Is it easy: Nope. And also I don't think there is any ready to use tools or snippets for this, so you would have to make it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @CarstenLøvboAndersen. Do you have any sample project or a link containing any sample?

Comment: no, It took me a month to build something like this.